# getting Error KeyError: (8, 'occurred at index 0') while integrating python code with Django . The code works in spyder

Tags: python, django, dataframe

I am trying to integrate a python code which works independently in spyder with Django which i am running in Atom.

Code below

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
month = request.POST.get('month')
start_month_no = request.POST.get('start_month')
month = int(month)


fin_data = pd.read_excel('C:\Resh\PythonWorkingDir\sample.xlsx', header=0)
fin_data = fin_data.drop(['Clarity Code', 'Additions to Projection if any', 
'Total Projection for the  Month INR',
                          'Invoiced Against Projection', 'Remarks'], axis=1)

fin_data.rename(columns={'SOW No/Work Order Number': 'SOW',
                         'PPM id': 'PPM',
                         'Project Name': 'ProjName'
                         },
                inplace=True)
print(fin_data)
fin_data.fillna(0, inplace=True)

prj_in_month = 5
inv_in_month = 6

for a in range(1, month + 1):
   fin_data[a] = fin_data.apply(lambda x: x[inv_in_month] - x[prj_in_month], axis=1)

   prj_in_month = prj_in_month + 2
   inv_in_month = inv_in_month + 2

   a = a + 1
```

---

The lamda function works when prj_in_month = 5 and inv_in_month = 6 , then it takes the values in the columns ( note 5 and 6 and positions and not column names). But when the loop runs second time it gives error KeyError: (8, 'occurred at index 0') which looks to me that second time its looking for the column name 8 instead of the 8th position. 
I do not want to pass the column names to lamda instead I want to pass the column positions.

The strange thing is the code works perfectly fine in spyder /pycham, but not when I add this in views.py in Django.

Can someone help me.

Thanks,
Reshmi

Comment: That's what it will do. In this line you do `fin_data[a] = fin_data.apply(lambda x: x[inv_in_month] - x[prj_in_month], axis=1)` after first iteration `inv_in_month` becomes 8 so it will look for that column name. If you can share same code to generate the dataframe or the xlsx file, people will be able to help you better.

Comment: but when the inv_in_month = 6 in the first iteration . it caculates the difference. Only when a=2 , that is in the second iteration, it goes wrong.

Comment: First iteration i get the difference that is it takes the values in the 6th column and 5th column and gives me back the difference . But when it goes for second iteration it checks for the column names 8 instead of 8th column.

Comment: Supplier Month          SOW    PPM               ProjName  Projection_Jan  \
0    a   Oct     ab   37901         abc             100   
1    a   Oct    ac   37800         cdv             800   
2    a   Oct     ad   60365      lmn             100   

   InvoicedAmt_Jan  Projection_Feb  InvoicedAmt_Feb  Projection_Mar  \
0               50             200              200             100   
1              500            1500             1500             200   
2               50             200              150             100